# Character encoding problems with reading a wvsx file

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I have a file which has wvsx extension. I'm trying to read lines at C#.  When I read and print the file, characters in the file gets converted into some ascii characters.

I tried all of Encoding chosen.
I can't see the result because I can't open the file anywhere.
Could smb advice a solution?

Comment: A `.vsx` file? Visio XML?

Comment: I am not sure. I'm getting this file from weaving machine.

Comment: Then most probably not a Visio file. The encoding can be anything. Software sometimes, for undefined reasons, uses the Local encoding (if this is an Encoding problem). Can you post a sample of the file or a link to download the file? Possibly, someone already knows the format or has the time to look *into* it.

Comment: How do you read and print the file? Please show us some of your effort.Try reading with Encoding.GetEncoding(1254), which is Turkish encoding.

Comment: Here is the example file link. https://easyupload.io/83fyyb

Comment: This is a binary file. Some format native to that software. You cannot read it as text. Does the software have some COM component? A name to the software might help here...

Comment: Software is running over the network to other machines. Weaving machine and software We @ velink. However, other special applications can read and write this file. Is it possible for me to do that? Thank you LocEngineer

Comment: I will try to give as much detail as I can. The software developed by the manufacturer for the machine is called "We @ velink" (https://www.vandewiele.be/en/activities/wevelink). With this program weaving work order is sent to the loom. Together with the image and the wvsx file, the loom decides how to weave it. What I need is to read this file in my own program and develop a software with the data in it.  There are some programs which can read data from this file.Unfortunately, I don't know how they do it because it's not open source. they are like third part application.

Comment: Sorry. You will have to contact the software manufacturer themselves. Especially since it is unclear whether you might be violating licensing restrictions. If not, they might be able to provide you with the necessary libraries to read and process this file format. As you say: it is not open source.